# Subspace or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm studying Functional Analysis and I got a doubt about the following theorem:

> Let $H$ be a prehilbert space and $S \subset H$ complete and convex. Then, $\forall x \in H$ there exists a unique best approximation vector of $x$ to $S$, i.e, there exists a unique $y \in S$ such that $d(x,S)=d(x,y)$ = $\|x-y\|$

I'm confused since in order to talk about completeness we need to talk about the metric, and it comes induced by the norm and we don't have guaranteed that $u-v \in S$ given that $u,v \in S$ unless $S$ is a subspace of $H$. So I don't know why it doesn't have to be a subspace.

Also, as a corollary,  I have that if $H$ is Hilbert and $S$ a closed **subspace**, the theorem holds. Moreover, this corollary claims the following:

> Assuming $y$ is the best approximation vector of $x$ to $S$, then $ x-y \perp   S \iff x-y \in S^{\perp}$

In this case, I don't understand the proof (it is in my notes taken in class, so I may have copied something wrong), since what seems to be proved is this:

- If  $x-y \in S^{\perp}$ then $y$ is the best approximation vector of $x$ to $S$.
- If $y$ is the best approximation vector of $x$ to $S$ then $ x-y \perp   S$

It seems nonsense to me, since $ x-y \perp   S$ and $x-y \in S^{\perp}$ both look the same to me. 
What would make sense to me is the following:

> Let $H$ be Hilbert and $S$ a closed **subspace**. Then $\forall x \in H$ there exists a unique best approximation vector of $x$ to $S$, $y$. Moreover,  $y$ is the best approximation vector of $x$ to $S$, $\iff$ $ x-y \perp   S$, i.e.$x-y \in S^{\perp}$

I'd like to know whether I'm right or not.

Comment: Once you have defined $d: H\times H\to\mathbb R$, you can restrict this function to $S\times S$ without worrying about where you got the original definition from. This makes $S$ into a metric space no matter whether it has a linear structure, and you can then speak about whether $S$ is complete _as a metric space_.

Comment: (i) You say it's clear if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $S$ is a closed subset. Note that actually $S$ has to be a closed _convex_ subset - maybe that's what you meant. Anyway, the proof of the result you say you have doubts about is exactly the same as the proof of this result that you say is clear! You say you have doubts - have you got doubts about the _proof_? (ii) It's hard to see what you mean by "$x-y\in S$, i.e., $x-y\in S^\perp$".

Comment: (I) Oh sorry. I meant **subspace**. I'm going to edit it.  Anyway, I say it is clear assuming the previous result .

Comment: $S$ doesn't have to be a subspace, just closed (or complete, if $H$ is not complete) and _convex_. The thing you say "seems to be proved" is nonsense - if $x-y\in S$ _and_ $x-y\in S^\perp$ then $x=y$. Impossible to say where the problem is unless you show us _why_ this "seems" to be proved.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're talking about a proof you read or a proof you found - if the latter you'll get better results if you _show_ us the proof.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I hope it now makes sense. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. The bit towards the end is just sloppy notation (whether your fault or the professor's we can't tell). Yes, $x-y\perp S$ and $x-y\in S^\perp$ mean the same thing, by definition. The sentence "If $A$ then $B\iff C$" doesn't really mean what it says - it was just an informal way of saying "If $A$ then $B$, which is the same as $C$".